# Execute command in variable bash script

Tags: shell

I have this .sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
CLASSPATH=$1
PACKAGE=$2
INPUT_FILE=$3

javac -classpath $CLASSPATH classes/$PACKAGE/$INPUT_FILE.java
cp classes/$PACKAGE/$INPUT_FILE.class ../WEB-INF/classes/$PACKAGE/

eval "$CATALINA"
```

And `$CATALINA` is set on .bashrc:

```
CATALINA_PATH="/var/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh"
CATALINA="sh $CATALINA_PATH stop && sh $CATALINA_PATH run"
```

But when I execute my .sh script it doesn't execute the command inside `$CATALINA`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate `doesn't execute the command inside $CATALINA`?

Comment: How do you know it is not running?  Do you get any error messages when you run the script?

Comment: It may be spurious, but is that really '/var/local/tomcat' and not '/usr/local/tomcat' ?  That might be the reason.

Comment: It runs in 1 second (it usually takes 5 or more seconds) and the server doesn't start.

I put in /var by purpose. If I execute $CATALINA outside the script it works perfectly.

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm using a variable that is inside .bashrc?

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm running a shell script, it uses a sub-shell so it cannot access the parent shell's environment.

Problem solved running the shell script in this way:

```
. ./script.sh
```